# How to access individual attribute like hour, minute from POSIXlt date object in R?

Tags: r

```
sampleDate <- "08/15/2015 00:00"
sampleDateObject <- strptime(sampleDate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Now how to get day, year, month etc. from this sampleDateObject?

Answer (score 1):

`sampleDateObject[['year']]`

will return 115, which is the number of years after 1900. Details available with `?POSIXlt`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer.

```
sampleDateObject$mon # to access month from 0-11
```

To access other attributes, check this page
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html